# Point/Feature to Raster-unwanted Grid of missing Data raster Cells-ArcGIS10.5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, arcgis-10.5, raster-conversion, missing-data

I tried to convert some point data (points on a regular grid of 100m by 100m) with the **Feature to Raster Tool** and the **Point to Raster Tool** (Rastersize of 100m) but in the resulting Rasterfile there is some kind of Grid of Rasters with Missing Values:

[image]

If I use the same tools with a resulting Rastersize of 200m ,it works perfectly fine.

Any suggestions what might be the reason and how to solve this, so I can convert the points into rasters of 100m ?

Additional information that might be a hint:
If you compare the position of the original points with the resulting raster cells, i can see that the closer the resulting raster cell is to the Grid of Rasters with Missing Values, the more the position of the original point is shifting towards the limitation of the resulting raster cell-please compare upper left raster and point with lower right:
[image]

Sorry for the different colors of the same problematic layers.

Comment: There is no point in the white areas in your screenshot. If you measure the distance across the white area between two points the distance is probably more than 100 m

Comment: Yeah thats the point. There should be a point in the middle. The same accounts for the other rasters. For some reason the points do not have the same position within the rasters and thus are shifting to the edges. And because the raster is smaller then 100 there is no point for the raster left in the white areas, that have the same size then the "normal" rasters. But i dont know why that is and how to change it.